# How to pass values correctly from editor to grid?

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have table bound to set of elements with nested value. I made custom editor for this element which is kendoDropDownList. It loads dictionary values from server. It works fine, when i edit values, but when i create new element, dropdown inserts Id value (data-value-field="Id").
So i recieve that:

```
{
  "Id":"",
  "DateFrom":"2013-12-06 15:43:39Z",
  "DateTo":"2013-12-06 15:43:39Z",
  "Person":"3e31b740-7ced-4232-8cfc-cb3e100e372f"
}
```

but i need

```
 {        
    "Id":"",
    "DateFrom":"2010-10-09 23:00:00Z",
    "DateTo":"2011-11-10 23:00:00Z",
    "Person": {            
        "Id":"eeb97990-d191-4508-93c1-55f9ca3681d5"
     }
 }
```

Comment: Thank you for help, i found solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution! I defined defaultValue for my nested entity in schema of my table's datasource, it works for me.